# iPhone EXIF/GPS Timestamp - Appears to be based on local settings?

Tags: iphone, camera, gps, exif

I was under the impression that the iPhone received timestamps along with GPS location data. While I can't say its not true for the internal database, it seems to be for the EXIF data attached to photos taken by the iPhone's camera.

I ran a test by turning **off** automatic date/time settings, ensuring my correct timezone was set.

I took a photo (`IMG_1692`), rolled back the time by two hours and took another (`IMG_1693`).

Using [Phil Harvey's EXIF Editor](https://ExifTool.org/), I retrieved this output:

```
$ exiftool IMG_1692.JPG | grep Time
File Modification Date/Time     : 2012:04:29 22:51:46+10:00
Exposure Time                   : 1/15
Date/Time Original              : 2012:04:29 22:51:46
GPS Time Stamp                  : 13:51:00
$ exiftool IMG_1693.JPG | grep Time
File Modification Date/Time     : 2012:04:29 20:51:32+10:00
Exposure Time                   : 1/15
Date/Time Original              : 2012:04:29 20:51:32
GPS Time Stamp                  : 11:40:50
```

You can clearly see the two hour difference in the file timestamp, as well as the GPS time!

Am I correct in this assertion that the GPS timestamp doesn't come from the GPS at all? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I correct in this assertion that the GPS timestamp doesn't come
>   from the GPS at all? Or am I missing something?

Your experiment definitely makes it look like that!

This very detailed web page [Exif Schema for Exif-specific Properties](http://www.exiv2.org/tags-xmp-exif.html) says:

> **GPS Time Stamp**: GPS tag 29 (date), 0x1D, and, and GPS tag 7 (time), 0x07. **Time stamp of GPS data, in Coordinated Universal
>   Time**. Note: The GPSDateStamp tag is new in EXIF 2.2. The GPS
>   timestamp in EXIF 2.1 does not include a date. If not present, the
>   date component for the XMP should be taken from exif:DateTimeOriginal,
>   or if that is also lacking from exif:DateTimeDigitized. If no date is
>   available, do not write exif:GPSTimeStamp to XMP.

It looks like what's happening is the `File Modification Date/Time` shows the local date & time according the phone's clock, in the phone's time zone.

This is then converted to [Coordinated Universal Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) ("UTC"), and saved as the `GPS Time Stamp`.

Comment: Ah yes, forgot to mention the UTC conversion! It would be ideal if iOS wrote both GPS Date and Time from the satellites..

Comment: Yes, and it would be great if developers had access to the GPS time... lot's of great things you can do with that!

Comment: Warning: Don't use the File Modification Date/Time for anything, since it is volatile. For example, you might export the photo and resave it in some way, thus changing the File Modification Date/Time. Use only persistent info such as Date/Time Original to learn when the photo was actually taken.