# Date/Time on iPad photos

Tags: ipad, photos, gps, time

I took a photo in Fayetteville Arkansas.  The EXIF info includes the following:

```
Date/Time Original: 2017:01:06 06:11:41
Lens Model:         iPad Air 2 back camera 3.3mm f/2.4
GPS Time Stamp:     12:11:39
GPS Date Stamp:     2017:01:06
```

I believe the reason the time difference is incorrect for Arkansas may be that I was traveling and still had a different time zone, and IOS does not actually get the GPS clock but "[computes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50001/iphone-exif-gps-timestamp-appears-to-be-based-on-local-settings)" UTC from the local time.  (Which is inappropriate, but that's another story).

However, neither date/time explains what Finder on MacOS says about it.  Finder says the image was created nine hours earlier than the EXIF local time and fifteen hours earlier than the GPS time.  Neither that date nor that time appears anywhere in the EXIF.  The iPad obviously could not have transferred to iCloud before the image was created, nor could the laptop download it before.  And the laptop sets its clock and zone from the net, which was obviously connected at download time.  Where does Finder get this from?
[image]

The result of `stat` is

```
User@MBP % find /Users/Shared/Sort_By_Date -name IMG_1759.JPG -exec stat  "{}" \;                       
16777221 1339383 -rwxrw-r-- 1 WGroleau staff 0 1672340 "Sep 13 22:52:10 2021" "Jan  5 21:11:41 2017" "Sep 14 11:50:21 2021" "Jan  5 21:11:41 2017" 4096 3272 0 /Users/Shared/Sort_By_Date/2017年/01月/06日/Fayetteville, AR - N College Ave, 06 January 2017/IMG_1759.JPG
```

The place/date directory was named by Photo during export

Comment: Which date/time is shown when you run `ls -l .../IMG_1759.JPG`? If you install an exif tool on your Mac, which date/time does it show for the photo?

Comment: PS: I still assume a timezone issue (especially because the minutes are the same), but having more data might help to figure out the details

Comment: I gave the EXIF data above.  `ls` won't show time if its more than a year old, but if shows the same date that Finder shows (5 Jan 2017).  And there are a lot of other images which Finder says were created before their content.  It's possible for the Photos app to have changed things, but after export and deletion from Photo, how would Finder come up with a date/time that does not exist in the file system nor in the EXIF?

Comment: You can use `stat` to get timestamps of older files in Terminal.

Comment: `stat` output added to question details.  Same info as Finder gives.