what causes incorrect time to show on imported iPhone & iPad pictures and how to make displayed time correct?
I saw a somewhat similar question from 2019 - but not exactly like this.  While in UK, using iPhone 15 pro and on local cell network with correct UK time showing on phone, I took pictures using iPhone camera.  When getting back to US I moved pictures to MacBook Pro using image capture.  Im on CST.   I have not edited pictures or messed with exif data.  I then synced them back to iPhone and iPad my usual way - cable & finder.
Now pictures in iPhone & iPad  display incorrect time in photo app while the ones on my MPB have the correct time.
Why is the time incorrect on iPad & iPhone & how to get the correct time the photo was taken to display - short of having to edit all the exif data??
Incorrect time on iPhone & iPad

Correct time on MacBook Pro

Photo airdropped back to MBP to show exif.  Finder on left , exif on right side.  Oddly enough I also k now notice the time showing in finder is 1 hour different from the picture when I posted above !!


Do you refer to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50001/iphone-exif-gps-timestamp-appears-to-be-based-on-local-settings ? What makes you assume it doesn’t apply in your case?

Another US to Europe and back photo time metadata question might have clues for you as well. both iPhone 15 pro. Do you know what version of iOS was present when you took the photos? On which device are the photos sorted correctly (without regard to correct exit data or not)?

@nohillside - because  that article is twelve years old.

EXIF is still a thing, 12 years later. Did you look at the metadata with an EXIF viewer (not with Photos), to see what is actually defined there?

@bmike - didn’t see that article in my search. Tks. I believe I was on iOS 18.0.1 as UK trip,was just this last Sept & don’t remember updating since. Correct sorting date & time on MacBook Pro. Correct sorting excluding time on iphone( photo source) and iPad. I have avoided messing with exif - just trying to figure out what’s causing the issue.

so ill add an edit above. when I airdrop one of the ones with the incorrect time from my iPad back to my mbp, the correct photo time shows in finder when the picture is displayed there.   the incorrect time shows in its exif data & timestamp info there in exif.

The “why” may take time as the “what” is still being sorted. Something is likely up for multiple people to notice errors in saving or processing times and time zones.
